# How to move LVM to new server

Tags: centos, lvm, upgrade, storage, san

The current setup of my server, I have a storage disk array (RAID60) which hold 110TB of data. All the data is stored in multiple volumes created by LVM. Now, I want to upgrade my server with Cent OS 5.8 to Cent OS 7. I am worried about any failure in upgrade process result in not accessing volumes. Is it possible to take backup of lvm configuration file and replace it when disaster happens. More importantly how can I migrate the lvm to a new server?